# PWA Project Server

Tags: pwa

I am trying to open the PWA site in Microsoft edge and i am having the error saying that This Project Server 2010 feature requires at least Microsoft Internet Explorer 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use IE11 when using PWA on Project Server 2010.

Comment: is that the only option? do we have any option using the EDGE?

Comment: Significant portions of 2010 require IE due to ActiveX controls; in addition, 2010 was never brought up to support MSFT Edge in any other scenario. Yes, IE is really your only solution.